# Perl: index/rindex after 2GB?

Tags: perl

index and rindex work great on short strings:

```
$ perl -e '$a=("x"x((2<<30)-2))."b";print index($a,"b")'
2147483646
$ perl -e '$a=("x"x((2<<30)-2))."b";print rindex($a,"b")'
2147483646
```

However, on long strings they behave quite differently:

```
$ perl -e '$a=("x"x((2<<30)-1))."b";print index($a,"b")'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ perl -e '$a=("x"x((2<<30)-1))."b";print rindex($a,"b")'
-1
```

Is this expected? Is there a nice workaround?

```
$ perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 18 subversion 2) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=linux, osvers=3.2.0-58-generic, archname=x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
    uname='linux brownie 3.2.0-58-generic #88-ubuntu smp tue dec 3 17:37:58 utc 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 gnulinux '
    config_args='-Dusethreads -Duselargefiles -Dccflags=-DDEBIAN -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Dldflags= -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Dlddlflags=-shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Dcccdlflags=-fPIC -Darchname=x86_64-linux-gnu -Dprefix=/usr -Dprivlib=/usr/share/perl/5.18 -Darchlib=/usr/lib/perl/5.18 -Dvendorprefix=/usr -Dvendorlib=/usr/share/perl5 -Dvendorarch=/usr/lib/perl5 -Dsiteprefix=/usr/local -Dsitelib=/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 -Dsitearch=/usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 -Dman1dir=/usr/share/man/man1 -Dman3dir=/usr/share/man/man3 -Dsiteman1dir=/usr/local/man/man1 -Dsiteman3dir=/usr/local/man/man3 -Duse64bitint -Dman1ext=1 -Dman3ext=3perl -Dpager=/usr/bin/sensible-pager -Uafs -Ud_csh -Ud_ualarm -Uusesfio -Uusenm -Ui_libutil -Uversiononly -DDEBUGGING=-g -Doptimize=-O2 -Duseshrplib -Dlibperl=libperl.so.5.18.2 -des'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='cc', ccflags ='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64',
    optimize='-O2 -g',
    cppflags='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.8.2', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='cc', ldflags =' -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /lib/../lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/../lib /lib /usr/lib
    libs=-lgdbm -lgdbm_compat -ldb -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt
    perllibs=-ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt
    libc=, so=so, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.so.5.18.2
    gnulibc_version='2.19'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=so, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags='-Wl,-E'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC', lddlflags='-shared -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: HAS_TIMES MULTIPLICITY PERLIO_LAYERS
                        PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                        PERL_HASH_FUNC_ONE_AT_A_TIME_HARD
                        PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_MALLOC_WRAP
                        PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV PERL_SAWAMPERSAND USE_64_BIT_ALL
                        USE_64_BIT_INT USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES
                        USE_LOCALE USE_LOCALE_COLLATE USE_LOCALE_CTYPE
                        USE_LOCALE_NUMERIC USE_PERLIO USE_PERL_ATOF
                        USE_REENTRANT_API
  Locally applied patches:
    DEBPKG:debian/cpan_definstalldirs - Provide a sensible INSTALLDIRS default for modules installed from CPAN.
    DEBPKG:debian/db_file_ver - http://bugs.debian.org/340047 Remove overly restrictive DB_File version check.
    DEBPKG:debian/doc_info - Replace generic man(1) instructions with Debian-specific information.
    DEBPKG:debian/enc2xs_inc - http://bugs.debian.org/290336 Tweak enc2xs to follow symlinks and ignore missing @INC directories.
    DEBPKG:debian/errno_ver - http://bugs.debian.org/343351 Remove Errno version check due to upgrade problems with long-running processes.
    DEBPKG:debian/libperl_embed_doc - http://bugs.debian.org/186778 Note that libperl-dev package is required for embedded linking
    DEBPKG:fixes/respect_umask - Respect umask during installation
    DEBPKG:debian/writable_site_dirs - Set umask approproately for site install directories
    DEBPKG:debian/extutils_set_libperl_path - EU:MM: Set location of libperl.a to /usr/lib
    DEBPKG:debian/no_packlist_perllocal - Don't install .packlist or perllocal.pod for perl or vendor
    DEBPKG:debian/prefix_changes - Fiddle with *PREFIX and variables written to the makefile
    DEBPKG:debian/fakeroot - Postpone LD_LIBRARY_PATH evaluation to the binary targets.
    DEBPKG:debian/instmodsh_doc - Debian policy doesn't install .packlist files for core or vendor.
    DEBPKG:debian/ld_run_path - Remove standard libs from LD_RUN_PATH as per Debian policy.
    DEBPKG:debian/libnet_config_path - Set location of libnet.cfg to /etc/perl/Net as /usr may not be writable.
    DEBPKG:debian/mod_paths - Tweak @INC ordering for Debian
    DEBPKG:debian/module_build_man_extensions - http://bugs.debian.org/479460 Adjust Module::Build manual page extensions for the Debian Perl policy
    DEBPKG:debian/prune_libs - http://bugs.debian.org/128355 Prune the list of libraries wanted to what we actually need.
    DEBPKG:fixes/net_smtp_docs - [rt.cpan.org #36038] http://bugs.debian.org/100195 Document the Net::SMTP 'Port' option
    DEBPKG:debian/perlivp - http://bugs.debian.org/510895 Make perlivp skip include directories in /usr/local
    DEBPKG:debian/cpanplus_definstalldirs - http://bugs.debian.org/533707 Configure CPANPLUS to use the site directories by default.
    DEBPKG:debian/cpanplus_config_path - Save local versions of CPANPLUS::Config::System into /etc/perl.
    DEBPKG:debian/deprecate-with-apt - http://bugs.debian.org/702096 Point users to Debian packages of deprecated core modules
    DEBPKG:debian/squelch-locale-warnings - http://bugs.debian.org/508764 Squelch locale warnings in Debian package maintainer scripts
    DEBPKG:debian/skip-upstream-git-tests - Skip tests specific to the upstream Git repository
    DEBPKG:debian/patchlevel - http://bugs.debian.org/567489 List packaged patches for 5.18.2-2ubuntu1 in patchlevel.h
    DEBPKG:debian/skip-kfreebsd-crash - http://bugs.debian.org/628493 [perl #96272] Skip a crashing test case in t/op/threads.t on GNU/kFreeBSD
    DEBPKG:fixes/document_makemaker_ccflags - http://bugs.debian.org/628522 [rt.cpan.org #68613] Document that CCFLAGS should include $Config{ccflags}
    DEBPKG:debian/find_html2text - http://bugs.debian.org/640479 Configure CPAN::Distribution with correct name of html2text
    DEBPKG:debian/hurd_test_skip_stack - http://bugs.debian.org/650175 Disable failing GNU/Hurd tests dist/threads/t/stack.t
    DEBPKG:fixes/manpage_name_Test-Harness - http://bugs.debian.org/650451 [rt.cpan.org #73399] cpan/Test-Harness: add NAME headings in modules with POD
    DEBPKG:debian/makemaker-pasthru - http://bugs.debian.org/660195 [rt.cpan.org #28632] Make EU::MM pass LD through to recursive Makefile.PL invocations
    DEBPKG:debian/perl5db-x-terminal-emulator.patch - http://bugs.debian.org/668490 Invoke x-terminal-emulator rather than xterm in perl5db.pl
    DEBPKG:debian/cpan-missing-site-dirs - http://bugs.debian.org/688842 Fix CPAN::FirstTime defaults with nonexisting site dirs if a parent is writable
    DEBPKG:fixes/memoize_storable_nstore - [rt.cpan.org #77790] http://bugs.debian.org/587650 Memoize::Storable: respect 'nstore' option not respected
    DEBPKG:fixes/net_ftp_failed_command - [rt.cpan.org #37700] http://bugs.debian.org/491062 Net::FTP: cope gracefully with a failed command
    DEBPKG:fixes/perlbug-patchlist - [3541c11] http://bugs.debian.org/710842 [perl #118433] Make perlbug look up the list of local patches at run time
    DEBPKG:fixes/module_metadata_security_doc - [68cdd4b] CVE-2013-1437 documentation fix
    DEBPKG:fixes/module_metadata_taint_fix - [bff978f] http://bugs.debian.org/722210 [rt.cpan.org #88576] untaint version, if needed, in Module::Metadata
    DEBPKG:fixes/IPC-SysV-spelling - http://bugs.debian.org/730558 [rt.cpan.org #86736] Fix spelling of IPC_CREAT in IPC-SysV documentation
    DEBPKG:fixes/fix-undef-source -
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Mar 27 2014 18:30:28
  %ENV:
    PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base "/home/tange/perl5""
    PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/tange/perl5"
  @INC:
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2
    /usr/lib/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/perl/5.18
    /usr/share/perl/5.18
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
    .
```

Comment: A 2g string is not so much long as it is ridiculous :-)

Comment: @GregHewgill Added -V

Comment: @paxdiablo where as a 2g-1 is just fine ?:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Schwern for the basic code. This version avoids copying in the 2 GB string by using `substr` directly. It supports the additional `$position` parameter like `index`. I also did the `rindex` version.

Call like `index`/`rindex` except call with a reference to to source string:

```
index64(\$string, $match);
index64(\$string, $match, $position);
rindex64(\$string, $match);
rindex64(\$string, $match, $position);


sub index64 {
    # Do index on strings > 2GB.
    # index in Perl < v5.22 does not work for > 2GB
    # Input:
    #   as index
    # Output:
    #   as index
    my $ref = shift;
    my $match = shift;
    my $pos = shift || 0;
    my $block_size = 2**31-1;
    my $strlen   = length($$ref);
    # No point in doing extra work if we don't need to.
    if($strlen < $block_size) {
        return index($$ref, $match, $pos);
    }

    my $matchlen = length($match);
    my $ret;
    my $offset = $pos;
    while($offset < $strlen) {
        $ret = index(
            substr($$ref, $offset, $block_size),
            $match, $pos-$offset);
        if($ret != -1) {
            return $ret + $offset;
        }
        $offset += ($block_size - $matchlen - 1);
    }
    return -1;
}

sub rindex64 {
    # Do rindex on strings > 2GB.
    # rindex in Perl < v5.22 does not work for > 2GB
    # Input:
    #   as rindex
    # Output:
    #   as rindex
    my $ref = shift;
    my $match = shift;
    my $pos = shift;
    my $block_size = 2**31-1;
    my $strlen = length($$ref);
    # Default: search from end
    $pos = defined $pos ? $pos : $strlen;
    # No point in doing extra work if we don't need to.
    if($strlen < $block_size) {
        return rindex($$ref, $match, $pos);
    }

    my $matchlen = length($match);
    my $ret;
    my $offset = $pos - $block_size + $matchlen;
    if($offset < 0) {
        # The offset is less than a $block_size
        # Set the $offset to 0 and
        # Adjust block_size accordingly
        $block_size = $block_size + $offset;
        $offset = 0;
    }
    while($offset >= 0) {
        $ret = rindex(
            substr($$ref, $offset, $block_size),
            $match);
        if($ret != -1) {
            return $ret + $offset;
        }
        $offset -= ($block_size - $matchlen - 1);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

[This bug was fixed](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/b464e2b7c8addfdd9b22b9a5949a89db7c73e43c) and will be in 5.22.0 which should be out in May.  It didn't make it into the 5.20.x series.  That patch is simple and you should be able to apply it to the 5.20.2 or 5.18.2 code base and recompile.

Regexes have the same problem, and it's also been fixed in 5.21.

The work around is to not have 2 gig strings in memory, that's good practice in general.  If it's read from a file, perhaps `read` it in blocks and use index on each block.

If you must have a 2 gig string, use substr() to check it in blocks.  Unfortunately this means you have to copy the string in pieces.  The code below deliberately initializes `$substr` outside the loop so Perl doesn't reallocate the memory multiple times.

```
use v5.18;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub big_index {
    my $ref = shift;
    my $match = shift;

    state $block_size = 2**29;

    my $strlen   = length($$ref);
    my $matchlen = length($match);

    # No point in doing extra work if we don't need to.
    return index($$ref, $match) if $strlen < $block_size;

    my $substr = '';
    my $offset = 0;
    for(
        my $offset = 0;
        $offset < $strlen;
        $offset += ($block_size - $matchlen - 1)
    ) {
        $substr = substr($$ref, $offset, $block_size);
        my $ret = index $substr, $match;
        return $ret + $offset if $ret != -1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Does that deal correctly with a $match spanning the border of two blocks? What does big_rindex look like?

Comment: @OleTange Dang, it doesn't.  You'd have to move in blocks which overlap at least the length of `$match`.  I fixed it.  rindex would work much the same, but `$offset` would start at `$strlen - $block_size` and `-=` the block window.